# Updated tables of maximal prime gaps?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

The website http://www.trnicely.net/gaps/gaplist.html contains a long list of maximal and nonmaximal prime gaps. In this list, the largest maximal prime gap is one of length 1476:

Size: 1476

Gap Start: 1425172824437699411

1476* CFC TOeSilva 2009  35.31    19  1425172824437699411

My question is if there are more updated lists of maximal prime gaps (with larger maximal prime gaps). If this is the case, I would like to know reliable sources for those lists.

Comment: Nicely's website says the list was last updated 5 January 2014. Sounds pretty up-to-date to me.

Comment: Maybe more nonmaximal prime gaps were added, but I would like to have a list with maximal prime gaps that are larger than 1476.

Comment: The largest maximal prime gap I see there is still 1476.

Comment: Are you under the impression that new maximal gaps are found every day? Do you have some reason to think some have been found in the last week-and-a-half?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I didn't include all the necessary details in the question. I saw Nicely's list including the maximal prime gap of 1476 several months ago, and today this is still the largest maximal prime gap. I thought that maybe there are other websites or resources with larger maximal prime gaps. But since Nicely's page was updated a few days ago, it seems that his website is the most reliable resource, and other websites showing maximal prime gaps are based on his web.

Comment: See also http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/gaps.html